# Convert swift struct to json string

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to convert my swift struct to json format. There seems to be quite a few questions like this, but none of the solutions has worked for me so far.

Here is my struct

```
struct Rec : Codable {
    var name:String
    var time:Int
    var values:[String]

    var jsonRepresentation : String {
        return """
            {
                "name":"\(name)",
                "time":\(time),
                "values":\(values)
            }
        """
    }
}
```

Here is the json format that the external api recieves.

```
{
    "op" : "delete",
     "rec": { 
        "name" : "some string",
        "time":200,

        "values": [ 
            "127.0.0.1"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my function the creates the HTTP request

```
 private func createPatchRequest(op: String, url: URL, rec: Rec) throws -> URLRequest {
    let dictionary: [String: String] = [
        "op":op,
        "rec":rec.jsonRepresentation
    ]

    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(dictionary)

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "PATCH"
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

    return request
}
```

I always get a 400 and i believe that swift isn't' encoding my json properly. I tried the request on postman and it worked fine!

Here is how it looked on postman

```
{
    "op" : "delete",
    "rec": { 
        "name" : "some string",
        "time":600,
        "values": [ 
            "127.0.0.1"
        ]
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: oops. just edited it. Its "rec" all the way

Comment: Since your struct is `Codable`, you don't have to do the weird manually created `jsonRepresentation` thing and then encode it, you can just directly call `JSONEncoder().encode(rec)`.  You would need to create a wrapper request struct that had `op` and `rec` properties and encode that one though

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the API expects `rec` to be a JSON object, but you're sending Rec as a string representation of a JSON Object. i.e. This is the JSON that you're sending:

```
{
  "rec": "{\n\"name\":\"some string\",\n\"time\":1,\n\"values\":[\"127.0.0.1\"]\n}",
  "op": "delete"
}
```

The ideal approach would be to create a `Codable` `PatchRequest` with a nested `Rec` struct and encode that. You can try the following snippet on Playground

```
struct Rec : Codable {
    var name:String
    var time:Int
    var values:[String]
}
struct PatchRequest : Codable{
    var op: String
    var rec: Rec
}

let rec = Rec(name: "some string",time: 600,values: ["127.0.0.1"])
let request = PatchRequest(op: "delete",rec: rec)

let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(request)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
```

This has the added benefit of reducing the number of parameters required by your API method and making the code cleaner overall:

```
private func createPatchRequest(url: URL, patchRequest: PatchReuest) throws -> URLRequest {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(patchRequest)
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    request.httpMethod = "PATCH"
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
    
    return request
}
```

Lastly, I would recommend using `let` in your structs instead of `var` unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Is there a reliable way to convert a string directly into a json? I think my `jsonRepresentation` function is decent. Even printed it out and it looked fine. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Ideally, if an API requests a JSONObject, you ought to create a struct that corresponds to that object and encode it directly using JSONEncoder. Trying to construct a json by formatting a string can lead to weird errors, such as in your case, where you were sending a string representation of a JSON Object instead of an actual json object.

Comment: @SomeGuyFortune Your `jsonRepresentation` would actually work (the fact that it was working was by change, never encode JSON by yourself!) but once you put it into a dictionary, it couldn't work because you were trying to encode a JSON with a JSON string inside.

Answer (score 1):

Your jsonRepresentation is a **string** but should be a **dictionary**. Update your struct this way:

```
struct Rec : Codable {
var name:String
var time:Int
var values:[String]

var jsonRepresentation: [String: Any] {
    return [
        "name": name,
        "time": time,
        "values": values
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope it helps! Please let me know if it worked.

Comment: Also, he should remove that `\(...)` everywhere and just use `name`, `time` and `values` directly! Values are still being converted to a `String` while you want an array of strings.

Comment: This is much cleaner than mine. But it seems like a better way would be to create a wrapper struct, that should also be Codable. So that swift can do a much better job encoding it to json. ` let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(someEncodableStructObject)`