# Swift Codable - How to encode custom array

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

That's my JSON case

```json
{
    "image_id" : 11101,
    "image_source_id" : 9,
    "image_author" : "",
    "image_copyright" : "",
    "image_format_list" : [
        {
            "image_format" : {
                "image_url" : "https://static.musixmatch.com/images-storage/mxmimages/1/0/1/1/1/11101_2.jpg",
                "image_format_id" : 2,
                "width" : 150,
                "height" : 150
            }
        },
        {
            "image_format" : {
                "image_url" : "https://static.musixmatch.com/images-storage/mxmimages/1/0/1/1/1/11101_16.jpg",
                "image_format_id" : 16,
                "width" : 451,
                "height" : 500
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I correctly decode my custom object in two different classes: MXMImage & MXMImageFormat.
But I can't figure out how to re-encode my object to rebuild the same JSON

That's my code:

```swift
struct MXMImage : Codable, Equatable {
    let imageId: Int
    let imageSourceId: Int
    let imageAuthor: String?
    let imageCopyright: String?
    let imageFormatList: [MXMImageFormat]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, Swift.CodingKey {
        case imageId
        case imageSourceId
        case imageAuthor
        case imageCopyright
        case imageFormatList
        
        enum ImageFormatListKey: String, CodingKey {
            case imageFormat
        }
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        imageId = try (container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .imageId) ?? 0)
        imageSourceId = try (container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .imageSourceId) ?? 0)
        imageAuthor = try? container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .imageAuthor)
        imageCopyright = try? container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .imageCopyright)
        
        var imagesFormatListContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .imageFormatList)
        var imagesList:[MXMImageFormat] = []
        while !imagesFormatListContainer.isAtEnd {
            let imageFormatContainer = try imagesFormatListContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.ImageFormatListKey.self)
            let imageFormat = try? imageFormatContainer.decode(MXMImageFormat.self, forKey: .imageFormat)
            if let imageFormat = imageFormat {
                imagesList.append(imageFormat)
            }
        }
        self.imageFormatList = imagesList
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        try container.encodeIfPresent(imageId, forKey: .imageId)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(imageSourceId, forKey: .imageSourceId)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(imageAuthor, forKey: .imageAuthor)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(imageCopyright, forKey: .imageCopyright)
        
        var imageContainer = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .imageFormatList)
        try imageFormatList?.forEach { imgFormat in
            var nested = imageContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.ImageFormatListKey.self)
            let data = try imgFormat.encoded()
            try nested.encode(data, forKey: .imageFormat)

        }
    }
}
```

In particular, I don't know how to re-indent my MXMImageFormat objects inside the key `image_format` and then encode the custom array. Is it possible to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include MXMImageFormat struct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert swift struct to json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119169/convert-swift-struct-to-json-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `nestedContainers` you could decode/encode a `[[String:MXMImageFormat]]` array and map it

```
struct MXMImage : Codable, Equatable {
    let imageId: Int
    let imageSourceId: Int
    let imageAuthor: String?
    let imageCopyright: String?
    let imageFormatList: [MXMImageFormat]?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case imageId,  imageSourceId,  imageAuthor, imageCopyright, imageFormatList}

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        imageId = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .imageId)
        imageSourceId = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .imageSourceId)
        imageAuthor = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .imageAuthor)
        imageCopyright = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .imageCopyright)
        if let imageFormatListData = try container.decodeIfPresent([[String:MXMImageFormat]].self, forKey: .imageFormatList) {
            imageFormatList = imageFormatListData.compactMap{$0["image_format"]}
        } else {
            imageFormatList = nil
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(imageId, forKey: .imageId)
        try container.encode(imageSourceId, forKey: .imageSourceId)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(imageAuthor, forKey: .imageAuthor)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(imageCopyright, forKey: .imageCopyright)
        if let imageFormatListData = imageFormatList {
            try container.encode(imageFormatListData.map{["image_format":$0]}, forKey: .imageFormatList)
        }
    }
}

struct MXMImageFormat : Codable, Equatable {
    let imageUrl : URL
    let imageFormatId, width, height : Int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `MXMImageFormat` is like this:

```
struct MXMImageFormat : Codable {
    let imageUrl: String
    let imageFormatId: Int
    let width: Int
    let height: Int
}
```

I think you are overthinking this. You can just do:

```
try imageFormatList?.forEach { imgFormat in
    var nested = imageContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.ImageFormatListKey.self)
    try nested.encode(imgFormat, forKey: .imageFormat)
}
```

Since `encode` accepts any `Encodable`, including `imgFormat`. You don't actually need to convert to a `Data` first (at least that's why you seem to be attempting to do).

Some test code:

```
let json = """
{
   "image_id": 11101,
   "image_source_id": 9,
   "image_author": "",
   "image_copyright": "",
   "image_format_list": [{
           "image_format": {
               "image_url": "https://static.musixmatch.com/images-storage/mxmimages/1/0/1/1/1/11101_2.jpg",
               "image_format_id": 2,
               "width": 150,
               "height": 150
           }
       },
       {
           "image_format": {
               "image_url": "https://static.musixmatch.com/images-storage/mxmimages/1/0/1/1/1/11101_16.jpg",
               "image_format_id": 16,
               "width": 451,
               "height": 500
           }
       }
   ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let model = try! decoder.decode(MXMImage.self, from: json)
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
let string = String(data: try! encoder.encode(model), encoding: .utf8)!
print(string) // this should be the same JSON as the one in the string literal
```

Also note that in `encode`, you don't have to use `try?` here:

```
while !imagesFormatListContainer.isAtEnd {
    let imageFormatContainer = try imagesFormatListContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.ImageFormatListKey.self)
    // here vvvvvvv
    let imageFormat = try? imageFormatContainer.decode(MXMImageFormat.self, forKey: .imageFormat)
    if let imageFormat = imageFormat {
        imagesList.append(imageFormat)
    }
}
```